# GitLab: Import changes from a bare repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a repo that I keep in GitLab that is my copy of the "upstream" code.  It gets delivered to me as a bare git repo.  The first time I put the bare repo on the server and imported it but now my question is this: how do I import the new copy (a new bare repo) into my existing repo in GitLab? In case it helps, here is the flow of events so far:

1. download tarball
2. copy to GitLab server
3. extract and import into GitLab
4. download updated tarball
5. ask this question

In the future, there will be local mods / branches that happen in between 3 & 4.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"4. download updated tarball" means you simply override your local repo with that updated tarball: a `git status` will detect the modified/added files and you can create a new commit based on those modifications.

Once this is done, you can push to GitLab.

I would advice doing that import in a dedicated branch (or in master, while you are doing your own modification in a dedicated branch).
The idea is to keep the branch where you override the content with the updated tarball clear of any other concurrent modifications.